# AngularJS - Getting invalid zip after downloading while extracting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to download a zip file by making post request. Fraom backend they are zipping the file and sending.

Backend Values they set

```
Content-Disposition →attachment;
filename="sample.zip"
Content-Type →application/zip
```

UI Code:

```
downloadMethod = function (path, item) {
      var promise = $http({ 
          method: "POST",
          data: item,
          url: API_SERVER.url+path,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/zip; charset=UTF-8'},
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      });
      promise.success(function(response, status, headers, conf) { 
        return response;
      }).error(function(response){
        return response;
      });
      return promise;
  };
```

On Success i am saving the file using Filesaver

```
var blob = new Blob([data)], {type:"application/zip"});
            saveAs(blob, "sample.zip");
```

The file is downloading. But while extracting the file I am getting the error

ERROR: CENTRAL DIRECTORY NOT FOUND

and also m getting File cannot be opened or it is not a valid zip file.

But when i try to hit the api from postman it is download and i can able to extract the file.

Comment: if response type is an array buffer, I don't think str2bytes will work as expected.

Comment: I tried without using Str2bytes also

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `.success` and `.error` methods with `.then` and `.catch` methods:

```
downloadMethod = function (path, item) {
      var promise = $http({ 
          method: "POST",
          data: item,
          url: API_SERVER.url+path,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/zip; charset=UTF-8'},
          responseType: 'arraybuffer'
      });
      promise.then(function(response) { 
        ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶;̶
        return response.data;
      }).catch(function(response){
        ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶;̶
        throw response;
      });
      return promise;
  };
```

The deprecated `.success` and `.error` methods **ignore return statements**.

Also notice that the signatures are difference.

For more information see

- [Why are AngularJS $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339)